# Error: SQLException in nextKeyValue when importing from MySQL to Hive using Sqoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, jdbc, hive, sqoop

The sqoop command used is following. I tried to add "convertToNull" in case there's 000:00:0 kind of values in the date but no luck.

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql://<ip_address>:6306/siki_asmet?serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8" --table asesor --username mic -P --hive-import --warehouse-dir /user/hadoop --hive-database siki_ods --m 1;
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:275)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:568)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:799)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: YEAR
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:85)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:751)
at org.apache.sqoop.lib.JdbcWritableBridge.readDate(JdbcWritableBridge.java:112)
at asesor.readFields(asesor.java:938)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:242)
... 12 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: YEAR
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
at com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:85)
at com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:50)
at com.mysql.cj.result.AbstractDateTimeValueFactory.createFromDate(AbstractDateTimeValueFactory.java:67)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MysqlTextValueDecoder.decodeDate(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:73)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:90)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:241)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.TextBufferRow.getValue(TextBufferRow.java:132)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: YEAR
at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2648)
at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)
at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)
at com.mysql.cj.result.SqlDateValueFactory.localCreateFromDate(SqlDateValueFactory.java:82)
... 22 more
```

Is is something related to Date format not being recognized?

Comment: It seems a problem with a year zero `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: YEAR`

Comment: but convertToNull should fix it no? in the Sqoop command

Comment: The [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_zerodatetimebehavior) reference this value `'0000-00-00\'` to be converted to NULL. This conversion apparently *does not happen*.